# Riemann sum problem.

Tags: calculus

I had a practice midterm that had the following question:

$A = \lim_{x \to\infty} R_n = \lim_{x \to\infty} (\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)\triangle x)$

Use this definition to find an expression for the area under the graph of $f(x) = \frac{log x}{x^2}$

So what I did:

$\triangle x = \frac{2}{n}$

$R_n = \lim_{x \to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\frac{log(1+\frac{2i}{n})}{(1+\frac{2i}{n})^2})*\frac{2}{n}$

According to any of the work I have done with practice questions this was the same approach I applied to all of them and got the right answer.

Now, in the answers version of the practice exam this was the answer:

$R_n = \lim_{x \to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (2in*\frac{log(n+2i)-log(n)}{(n+2i)^2})$

How is he obtaining this final answer?

Comment: There seem to be a couple small errors.  Instead of $x$ don't you want $n$.  And the sum should be over $i$.  Then, finally,  I don't know where the $i$ out in front comes from in the answer.

Comment: I corrected the sigma notation. thank you

Comment: Are you referring to the $i$ in the answer my prof gave us which is the part I dont understand?

Comment: Yes i am.  Maybe it's a mistake.

Comment: Could be, ill have to ask him. I just don't see how he derived his answer, and like i said it is different then all the other ones I have done.

Comment: area under the graph, on what interval? (Also, several $x\to\infty$ should likely be $n\to\infty$?)

Answer (score 1):

I get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n 2n\cdot \frac{\log(n+2i)-\log n}{(n+2i)^2}$.

This is straight forward using $\log\frac ab=\log a-\log b$, plus a little algebra.

Comment: Ok I get that, reducing using log properties, but $2in$?

Comment: Seems to be wrong.

Comment: Must be. Thank you